# A problem about inferring argument in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

The following are some Ocaml codes using Ocaml and Yojson (a library support Json for Ocaml).

```
match feat_json with
| `Assoc [("goal",`List goal_feats_json); 
  ("tactic", `String tac_str); ("arguments",`List args_feats_json)] ::tl ->
```

Then I show the definition of Yojson json type

```
type json = [ `Assoc of (string * json) list
       | `Bool of bool
       | `Float of float
       | `Int of int
       | `List of json list
       | `Null
       | `String of string ]
```

Both of `goal_feats_json` and `args_feats_json` have the type `json`.
The concrete type of `goal_feats_json` is `[< Int of int ] list`. The type of `tac_str` is `string`.
The concrete type of `args_feats_json` is `[> Assoc of (string * [> Int of 'b | String of 'c ]) list ] list`. 
But when I compiled the file, the following error occurred.

```
Error: This expression has type [< `Int of 'a ] list but an expression was expected of type
         [> `Assoc of (string * [> `Int of 'b | `String of 'c ]) list ] list*
```

It seems Ocaml treats both of `goal_feats_json` and `args_feats_json` as `[< Int of int ] list`. I have no idea why such an error happened. I would be much appreciated if anyone gives me some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error in the code snippet that you showed, so it is impossible to know where lies the root issue. However, your type error can be solved with an explicit coercion. For instance,

```ml
let f (x:[< `Int of int]) = (x:>json)
```

Probably, you used `goal_fets_json` as an argument of a function that only works with values of type `[<`Int of _]` at some point, restraining its type.

Comment: Thanks very much! I use `goal_fets_json` as an argument of a function which only works with *[ Int of _]*. Could you give me some help with why my code restrains its type?

Comment: Because it is of the right thing to do if your code only works with values of type `[ Int of _ ]`? I am not sure what is your question?